# How to perform linear interpolation of value from a list (C#)

Tags: c#, object, dictionary, interpolation

I apologize that this is probably programming 101, but I have limited experience as programming is not a day-to-day activity for me. I also apologize if this has been answered a million times before but I was unsuccessful in finding it in search as I am unsure what this would be considered (dictionary? object? list?)

I would like to create a list of ordered **doubles** that correspond to specific properties I am interested in such as below:

[(a1, a2, a3,...),(b1,b2,b3,...),(c1,c2,c3,...),...]

My program will calculate an input (a_input) which will most likely be between the list of values such as for example:

a3 < a_input < a4

I will then like the program to recognize that it is between a3 and a4 and use this information to linearly interpolate for the other values such as:

(a_input - a3)/(a4 - a3) = (c_input - c3)/(c4-c3)

this will output the values that I am interested in (e.g. c_input) to run the rest of my program.

How exactly would I make this happen? I have considered a dictionary approach, but I do not want key strings as all the values could easily be ordered numbers.

Any input or direction of where to find the information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [What have you tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: I would just order the a0-an in a List, then use [BinarySearch()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh.aspx) against the input. If it returned n where n is positive number, then the input is exactly an, if it's negative, the input is between a[~n] and a[~n]+1

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Martheen.

Unfortunately I do not believe it will be this simple.

a1,a2,a3,... all correspond to properties of the same object while b1,b2,b3,.. etc.  correspond to properties of a different object so I am unsure how I will be able to order the list.

Comment: A dictionary would be exactly what you'd need if this is time-series data.

Comment: Thanks for your input FirebladeDan. As I mentioned before I am not an experienced programmer. The only dictionary I am familiar with is a string with one value, which as you mentioned would be great for time-series. Would I need to set up multiple dictionaries (they would need to be ordered so they would correspond to each other)? Such as {a} = [("prop1", a1), ("prop2",a2),...] {b}=[("prop1",b1),("prop2",b2),...]

Comment: may be List with the array of doubles?  `List<double[]>`
you may create array with object properties, then sort it `Array.Sort(myArray);` and add to the list

Comment: Show a more concrete example. We're still trying to figure out what a1, a2, b3, etc. are.

Comment: Jim, my actual application is with properties of fluids at different temperatures such as in this website http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/air-properties-d_156.html. 

My program outputs a temperature and I will need to use this in order to find the other properties to use in the rest of the code. However the temperature my program outputs is likely to be between temperatures so I would like to interpolate between each for more accurate numbers. So "a" , "b", "c" would be the different rows and "1", "2", "3" would be the different columns. For example e4 would be (5,4) or k=0.0257.

Comment: So an example would be that my program outputs a temperature of T= 50C. I would need the program to then determine that 50C is between 40C ("f1") and 60C ("g1") within the dictionary(s). It would then interpolate between these values to find the other values I am after. for example (T-f1)/(g1-f1) = (k-f4)/(g4-f4) --> (50-40)/(60-40) = (k-0.0271)/(0.0285-0.0271) to solve for k. I do not know if I am doing very well at explaining this. Please let me know if you would like me to give a more thorough example.

Answer (score 0):

you got it way wrong

create a class of your properties
add them in order of temp or you can sort on the foreach

```
class PhysicalProperties 
{
    public double Temp { get; set; }
    public double Vis  { get; set; }
    public double Dens { get; set; }
}

List<PhysicalProperties> ListPhysicalProperties = new List<PhysicalProperties>(); 
// add the PhysicalProperties in temp order

PhysicalProperties fpUnder;
PhysicalProperties fpOver;
foreach(PhysicalProperties fp in ListPhysicalProperties) 
{
   if(f.Temp >= temp) 
   {
       fpOver = fp;
       break:
   }
   fpUnder = fp;
}

// do the liner interpolation on fpUnder and fpOver  
// check for possible null
```

there is also LINQ but since you have to get the prior I think looping is the way to go
i doubt you are going to have more than 1000 temps

p.s. I have a B.S in chemical engineering
float may be big enough for you

Comment: Hi Paparazzi,

Thanks for your suggestion on simplifying the code. I have not worked with classes before, and I am not entirely sure about everything you have coded, but I think I have the general concept (looping through the classes by physicalproperty "temp" with the condition f.Temp >= temp). I am not really sure what "fpUnder" and "fpOver" are referring to nor how the get; set; accessors work  nor where to input the values from the table. I will look into working with classes and see if I am able to understand what you are suggesting and possibly implement them into my code.

Answer (score -1):

I am sure there are much more efficient/simple ways of accomplishing this but the following snippet is how I was able to look up and interpolate the value for rho. The output I received was Rho=1.1855 which is what would be expected. I will be able to use this to also interpolate for the other values using this method. Thank you all for taking a look at my problem, and if anyone has any suggestions to simplify the code please let me know.

```
//Dictionaries for the different air properties
                //Air properties for T=0
        Dictionary<string, double> a = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        {
            a.Add("T",0);
            a.Add("Rho", 1.293);
            a.Add("Cp", 1.005);
            a.Add("k", 0.0243);
            a.Add("Nu", 13.30*Math.Pow(10,-6));
            a.Add("Betta", 3.67 * Math.Pow(10, -3));
            a.Add("Pr", 0.715);
        }
            //Air properties for T=20
        Dictionary<string, double> b = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        {
            b.Add("T", 20);
            b.Add("Rho", 1.205);
            b.Add("Cp", 1.005);
            b.Add("k", 0.0257);
            b.Add("Nu", 15.11 * Math.Pow(10, -6));
            b.Add("Betta", 3.43 * Math.Pow(10, -3));
            b.Add("Pr", 0.713);
        }
         //Air properties for T=40
        Dictionary<string, double> c = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        {
            c.Add("T", 40);
            c.Add("Rho", 1.127);
            c.Add("Cp", 1.005);
            c.Add("k", 0.0271);
            c.Add("Nu", 16.97 * Math.Pow(10, -6));
            c.Add("Betta", 3.20 * Math.Pow(10, -3));
            c.Add("Pr", 0.711);
        }

        //temporary values for example
        double T = 25;
        double Rho=0;

        // Code for property lookup
        if (T <= a["T"])
        {
            Rho = a["Rho"];
        }
        else if (T == b["T"])
        {
            Rho = b["Rho"];
        }
        else if (T < c["T"])
        {
            Rho = (T - b["T"]) * (c["Rho"] - b["Rho"]) / (c["T"] - b["T"]) + b["Rho"];
        }
        else
            Rho = c["Rho"];
```

Comment: Wow it worked for three whole temps.   What are you going to do with 4 or 40?   And then rinse and repeat for every property.

Comment: I do not understand why you are being so condescending. I clearly said that your option was more efficient, but am not sure how to code at that ability yet since I am still new to coding.

Comment: It a combination of your question and answer.  You have two down votes and two votes to close and have done nothing to clean up your question.  All that is in your question is how to do a Dictionary and this is the wrong approach.  I only figured what you want from a vague comment only because that is (was) my field.   The title is how to perform linear interpolation and you know how to do that.